# Publishing MVC site with Visual Studio to IIS 7 removes custom response headers from IIS config

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, webdeploy

I'm using IIS 7 and I've got a site setup with an additional HTTP response header (`X-UA-Compatible` header).

I'm deploying an MVC4 project remotely to IIS using the Publish feature in Visual Studio 2010, which uses Web Deploy.

Problem is, every time I publish the site, the HTTP response header gets removed from the config in IIS - is there some way I can prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - when you set headers at the site level in IIS 7, it alters the web.config file. I needed to add a `customHeaders` element in the web.config file that is deployed:

```
<system.webServer>
...
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>    
... 
</system.webServer>
```